# Scala using JSON and/or XML templates

Tags: xml, json, scala, template-engine, scalatra

I am using Scalatra, but this question should be valid for any Scala programming. I come from a Ruby on Rails background. Simply put, using templating systems such as XML Builder or jsonbuilder (https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), I had full control on what my JSON or XML output in an RESTful API would be by creating a template such as the following:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.content format_content(@message.content)
  json.(@message, :created_at, :updated_at)

  json.author do
    json.name @message.creator.name.familiar
    json.email_address @message.creator.email_address_with_name
    json.url url_for(@message.creator, format: :json)
  end

  if current_user.admin?
    json.visitors calculate_visitors(@message)
  end

  json.comments @message.comments, :content, :created_at

  json.attachments @message.attachments do |attachment|
    json.filename attachment.filename
    json.url url_for(attachment)
  end
end
```

The ideal here is, I put together a `@message` object with whatever logic is required in a controller+action. That gets passed to a template that has logic such as `if current_user.admin?` include some stuff, otherwise don't.

What is the equivalent tool that's available in Scala or Scalatra to do something similar? I know a `serializer` will let me override the JSON or XML that gets generated from a particular model, but that's the same thing in Ruby (correct me if I'm wrong) as overriding `as_json` or `as_xml`. Sometimes however, templates are much more complicated and include multiple models, specific structuring of data, specific ordering of data, etc. This is the flexibility I need. Is there current a tool that allows for such templating in a Scala/Scalatra environment?

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately I don't know any really good library to do this in XML (although [Anti-Xml](http://anti-xml.org/) is worth taking a look). But there are such library for Json and it's the [PlayJson](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-alone)
With play json you can do basically everything you can do with Ruby's JsBuilder, except some paradigm difference:

1. Scala tries to be as functional as possible and many many libraries operate with unmutable data structures. Play json is not an exception. This means that you cannot **just change** some value deep in the json tree, you need to reconstruct the whole json object
2. Scala is a statically typed language. Which is great, because compiler checks all type-signatures for correctness, except we must provide those signatures.

Here's example code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

case class Attachment(fileName: String, url: String)
case class Author(name: String, email: String, url: String)
case class Comment(content: String, created_at: DateTime)
case class Post(author: Author, content: String, attachments: List[Attachment], comments: List[Comment], created_at: DateTime, updated_at: DateTime)

object Main {

  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  val isAdmin = true

  def calculateVisits(post: Post) = 35

  implicit val jodaTimeWrites: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
    def writes(c: DateTime): JsValue = {
      Json.toJson(c.toString(DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime()))
    }
  }
  implicit val attachmentFormat = Json.format[Attachment]

  implicit val authorWrites: Writes[Author] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "email").write[String] and
    (__ \ "url").write[String]) { unlift(Author.unapply) }

  implicit val commentWrites: Writes[Comment] = (
    (__ \ "content").write[String] and
    (__ \ "created_at").write[DateTime]) { unlift(Comment.unapply) }

  implicit val postWrites: Writes[Post] = (
    (__ \ "content").write[String] and
    (__ \ "created_at").write[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "updated_at").write[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "author").write[Author] and
    (__ \ "visitors").write[Option[Int]] and
    (__ \ "comments").write[List[Comment]] and
    (__ \ "attachments").write[List[Attachment]]) { post: Post =>
      (
        post.content,
        post.created_at,
        post.updated_at,
        post.author,
        if (isAdmin) Some(calculateVisits(post)) else None,
        post.comments,
        post.attachments)
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val post = Post(
      Author("David H.", "david@heinemeierhansson.com", "http://example.com/users/1-david.json"),
      "<p>This is <i>serious</i> monkey business</p>",
      List(
        Attachment("forecast.xls", "http://example.com/downloads/forecast.xls"),
        Attachment("presentation.pdf", "http://example.com/downloads/presentation.pdf")),
      List(
        Comment("Hello everyone!", new DateTime()),
        Comment("To you my good sir!", new DateTime())),
      new DateTime(),
      new DateTime())

    Console println (Json prettyPrint (Json toJson post))
  }

}
```

Notice the `attachmentFormat` - it is generated by scala macros to be matched with case class definition. In my project I've never written a single manual Format override compiler generates all formats for me! But I can If I need to. Good example is the `jodaTimeWrites` - default jodaTimeFormat will generate long value which is more appropriate for machine processing, but I have overridden it with my own implicit format to match ruby's sample.

The code above produces following output:

```
{
  "content" : "<p>This is <i>serious</i> monkey business</p>",
  "created_at" : "Friday, July 5, 2013 4:19:42 PM +03:00",
  "updated_at" : "Friday, July 5, 2013 4:19:42 PM +03:00",
  "author" : {
    "name" : "David H.",
    "email" : "david@heinemeierhansson.com",
    "url" : "http://example.com/users/1-david.json"
  },
  "visitors" : 35,
  "comments" : [ {
    "content" : "Hello everyone!",
    "created_at" : "Friday, July 5, 2013 4:19:42 PM +03:00"
  }, {
    "content" : "To you my good sir!",
    "created_at" : "Friday, July 5, 2013 4:19:42 PM +03:00"
  } ],
  "attachments" : [ {
    "fileName" : "forecast.xls",
    "url" : "http://example.com/downloads/forecast.xls"
  }, {
    "fileName" : "presentation.pdf",
    "url" : "http://example.com/downloads/presentation.pdf"
  } ]
}
```

Now instead of 21 lines of ruby code I got 33 lines of scala's somehow more complicated mappings (without case classes). Why type more? Because now I'm dead certain that when I pass `Comment` instead of `Attachment` I'll get compiler error, or when my colleague will change by mistake joda.time.DateFormat to java.util.DateFormat he'll receive error instead of some gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of an answer using Scala's built-in XML literals and the excellent [argonaut.io](http://argonaut.io) JSON serialization library:

```
// dependencies for use with scala 2.10.2:
// "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.0-RC3"
// "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.1"

import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

object ArgonautJsonExample extends App {

  case class File(name: String, url: String = "http://my.dummy.url")
  case class Message(name: String, isAdmin: Boolean, attachmentOpt: Option[File])
  val message =
    new Message(
      "Erik",
      true,
      Some(File("strawberry.png"))
    )

  val json: Json =
    ("name" := message.name) ->:
    ("filename" :=? message.attachmentOpt.map(_.name)) ->?:
    ("url" :=? message.attachmentOpt.map(_.url)) ->?:
    jEmptyObject


  val myXml =
    <myObject>
      <author>
        <name>{message.name}</name>
      </author>
      {
        message.attachmentOpt map { file =>
          <attachment url={file.url}>
            {file.name}
          </attachment>
        } getOrElse xml.NodeSeq.Empty
      }
    </myObject>


  println("json = " + json)
  println("")
  println("xml = " + myXml)

}
```

This will will give you:

```
json = {"url":"http://my.dummy.url","filename":"strawberry.png","name":"Erik"}

xml = <myObject>
  <author>
    <name>Erik</name>
  </author>
  <attachment url="http://my.dummy.url">
        strawberry.png
      </attachment>
</myObject>
```